# How to loop over simple inventory on Ansible?

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following Ansible inventory:

```
[UP]
u01
u02
```

I want print hostnames under the UP group and then store each hostname in a variable

I tried the following playbook with the command: `ansible-playbook test_playbook.yml -i inventory`

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost

  tasks: 
    - name: Show all the hosts in the inventory
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['UP'] }}"
      register: result
```

I'm getting the following errors instead:

```
TASK [Show all the hosts in the inventory] *************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=u01) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 0, "item": "u01"}
failed: [localhost] (item=u02) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 0, "item": "u02"}
```

I can't seem to find the error to correct it, does anyone have any clue ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ahmed El Amine Boukemoune welcome to SO. I cannot reproduce that behavior, but `env ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible-playbook -vvvv` should emit every piece of debugging info it has in order to see what the underlying issue is. I'd _guess_ your `ansible_python_interpreter` is bogus but I agree that is a very unhelpful error message. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: UP

  tasks: 
    - name: Show all the hosts in the inventory
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      register: result
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      with_inventory_hostnames:
        - UP
```